# VSTS: Cannot change value of a user defined variable in release

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

So, I created the variable *counter* with initial value -1.

[image]

Then in a *Release*, I tried to change its value to 1 using Powershell script:

[image]

But the value didn't change:
[image]

However, I tested this in a *Build* and it worked as expected. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of this command is to set a variable that persists across tasks. Therefore it will only be guaranteed to be available in the next PowerShell task that you run since it can take a bit to take effect (and you were probably lucky in your build but effectively it is a race condition).
The documentation [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) backs up the fact that you should rather define variables in a task of its own before using them later:

> Sets a variable in the variable service of taskcontext. The first task can set a variable, and following tasks are able to use the variable. The variable is exposed to the following tasks as an environment variable. When issecret is set to true, the value of the variable will be saved as secret and masked out from log. Secret variables are not passed into tasks as environment variables and must be passed as inputs.

Comment: I examined the variable value in a new PowerShell subsequent task and it returned -1 which means the value didn't change at all. Still, the weird thing is that this works perfectly in a _Build_ but not in a _Release_.

Comment: Just tried with starian chen-MSFT suggestion and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable="counter"] 1"` to `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=counter] 1"` (remote double quotes from `"counter"`)

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm but as bermeister pointed out only for the subsequent tasks which is fine to me.